# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
viewHolder.itemView.task_contrtaintLayout_task.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG,"Clicked $taskId Body")
                val intent = Intent(this, EditTaskActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

I'm trying to create an intent inside the ViewHolder, why does this bug come out? The same thing happens when I try to make a toast, how do I define the context in this case?

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:  public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

Comment: The question is bad, the answers are good, but mine will not work

Comment: `val intent = Intent(this, EditTaskActivity::class.java)` This line of code was written wrong. Inside of click Listener event you should use Context. change `this to context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to start a new activity from RecyclerView adapter from item holder. For normal intent working you have two ways:

1. Pass context to the adapter's constructor and use it in intent:

   ```
   val intent = Intent(context, SomeActivity::class.java)
   context.startActivity(intent)
   ```
2. Use interface class which will call fragment/activity method from the adapter click listener.

For more info about intents you can [read documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Have context as a parameter to the Adapter class. Then access the context inside your ViewHolder Class.

```
class CartImagesAdapter(val items : List<String>, val context: Context) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

 // Gets the number of animals in the list
   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
  return items.size
 }
 // Inflates the item views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder 
{
  return 
 ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_payment_method, 
  parent, false))
   }

// Binds each animal in the ArrayList to a view
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


 }}
 class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
 // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
  view.itemView.task_contrtaintLayout_task.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG,"Clicked $taskId Body")
            val intent = Intent(context, EditTaskActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }   }
```